# If, then, else function in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using the below code in access.

I am trying to set it so that the 2 text boxes can not be left blank, if they have dates in then it will proceed to generate a report.

```
    If IsNull(Me.txtStart.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please ensure that both date fields are populated"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtEnd.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please ensure that both date fields are populated"
    Exit Sub
Else
End If
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the problem? If either text box is empty the code returns without doing anything. You don't need the `Else` just add your code that uses these values after the if statement.

Comment: When I try to run the report with the fields blank I get the msgbox,, but when both textboxes have dates in the msgbox still shows but it should show the report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```vb
If IsNull(Me.txtStart.Value) Or IsNull(Me.txtEnd.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please ensure that both date fields are populated"
    Exit Sub
End If
' open the report here
```

No need to use `Else` after an `Exit Sub`.

Actually I prefer this coding style for initial checks over large `Else` cases.

Comment: The code you posted works, however When (me.txtStart.Value) textbox is empty, it doesn't recognise it as empty and runs the report.

Comment: @Wolfie84367: `txtStart` should be a date field that accepts only NULL (empty) or a date. There should be no ambiguity possible. This is easiest done by assigning a "Date" format to the `Format` property of the textbox.